# Thinktecture IdentityServer V3 - Data is not binding and resources are not loading

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

I've recently created an Web API that I'd like secured by Thinktecture's IdentityServer V3. I imported the package from nuget, and was able to hit the token endpoints to create a token. However, I noticed that the bootstrap css would not load on IS's main page:

This is how it appears i.imgur.com/DftMQ7C.png vs https:/demo.getidentityserver.com

It didn't bother me until I started using the views (and not just the endpoints) where my pages would print the variable names and function incorrectly with the resources not loading properly. [Like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyntF.png)
Of course, I can not log in since it redirects me the [literal "loginUrl" page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JoXp.png). I've tried reverting to the previous version 1.2.1, but I still have the same issue. Alternatively, I've looked at samples and those don't have the same issue at all, so I'm wondering if there's a config in my API project that may be causing this.

Has anyone encountered this problem or know of a potential fix?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to read through the documentation thoroughly, guys. Lesson learned. I just needed to add RAMMFAR to my web.config "otherwise some of the embedded assets will not be loaded correctly by IIS"

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```